# How to register username password fields from sql in mongooseim server

Tags: mysql, linux, erlang, ubuntu-12.04, mongoose-im

I have created 2 accounts in my localpc and then after I registered it with mongooseim. I am able to login mongooseim through converseJS client.

Now I want to login mongooseim from mysql tables fields(username, password), without creating new accounts in localpc, in short mongooseim should authenticate users from sql-database only.

Answer (score 1):

After mongooseim 1.5.0 you can set up MySQL with Mongooseim with instructions below,

You should create database named ejabberd and then
you should create your tables with [mysql.sql](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/blob/master/apps/ejabberd/priv/mysql.sql)

```
mysql -h localhost -p -u root
```

Enter your password

```
GRANT ALL ON ejabberd.* TO 'ejabberd'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

CREATE DATABASE ejabberd;
```

Now exit from mysql

Recreate tables

```
mysql -D ejabberd -h localhost -p -u ejabberd < mysql.sql
```

In the ejabberd.cfg comment out auth_method internal and activate auth_method odbc
and then activate MySQL Server setup with your password

```
%% MySQL server:

%%

{odbc_server, {mysql, "localhost", 3306, "ejabberd", "ejabberd", "password"}}.
```

Comment: mysql -D ejabberd -h localhost -p -u ejabberd < mysql.sql
bash: mysql.sql: No such file or directory
I have created database as 'ejabberd' and table 'mysql' in it(You should create database named ejabberd and then you should create your tables with mysql.sql).

Comment: you don't need to create mysql table. Where is your mysql.sql? You should change your directory when applying that code with cd.

Comment: oops I forgot to update here I through with this part. Now the error which i am facing is with erlang-mysql driver issue, App unable to pick odbc-related-modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your server to use ejabberd database authentication.

This is done with module ejabberd_auth to work with odbc and choosing odbc type MySQL.

Please read, this part of the documentation:
http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc25